# device motion in constrained environment

Tags: iphone, ios, gyroscope, core-motion

I am trying to solve a seemingly easy problem related to device motion but couldn't figure out how to solve it.  I have a situation where iPhone will move in a circle in the x-y plane.  I need to find the angle between the iPhone's x and y axes relative to the center of rotation.  The iPhone may be in portrait mode or landscape mode or in any angle in between relative to the line connecting iphone to the center of rotation.  See the attached picture that explains the scenario.

The yaw change for a given rotation is the same regardless of this angle, so that doesn't really help.  I am hoping that there would be some relationship that I can calculate for every small rotation and then find the best fit for the entire motion - but can't figure out that yet.

I appreciate any help or pointers.

[image]

Comment: What you're describing seems like a constrained case of _dead reckoning_. In general dead reckoning is very hard (can barely work if you apply Kalman filter). I'm not sure whether move on a circle constrains it enough to avoid problem of imprecision of double integration.

Comment: @porneL He is only tracking orientation so he can avoid the double integral.

Comment: After reading a bit on dead reckoning - yes, that is what I was think of.  I was thinking of avoiding cumulative error by taking every instance of two consecutive positions as an independent point.  I can get the change in angle through yaw change and the distance traveled through delta x and delta y (although not sure how would I apply Kalman filter).

Comment: @ae262 So does this mean that you also need the diameter of the big circle in your picture?

Comment: No, I only need the angle between the device and the line connecting device to the center of rotation.

Comment: @ae262 I can give you the axis and the angle of rotation in 3 lines of code. However, I am still confused. Do you know that the iPhone initially sits on one of the axes (positive part of y axis in your picture)? If yes, then I believe I have the answer.

Comment: @Ali -  No, that was only for illustration.  That said, I am still very curious on how would you solve the problem if that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

(I am writing in pseudo-code since I don't know the API you are using, sorry.)

Here is how to get the axis and angle of the rotation.

Get the rotation matrices `R1` and `R2` at the beginning and end of your rotation directly from the API (see CMAttitude and CMRotationMatrix). Then, determine the `angle` and `axis` of the rotation `R` that brings `R1` to align with `R2`. You get `R` as follows:

```
R = R1 * transpose(R2)
```

The angle of rotation `R` is

```
angle = acos((trace(R)-1)/2)
```

and its axis is

```
axis = { R[3][2]-R[2][3], R[1][3]-R[3][1], R[2][1]-R[1][2] }
```

For further details, please check [Rotation matrix to axis angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Axis_and_angle) and also [Axis-angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-angle_representation#Log_map_from_SO.283.29_to_so.283.29).

---

I am not sure how to get the angle you are interested in. Nevertheless, I hope that the above helps.

---

Please don't use roll, pitch and yaw anything other than display. And don't try to integrate them, nothing good will come out.

Anyways, behind the rotation matrices there is integration. In other words, somebody already did the integration for you.

Comment: Thanks!  I need to do some reading to refresh the rotation matrix etc. and better understand what you described.  I am not sure what that axis is but I think it may help me get the angle between the device and axis of rotation.

Comment: your answer didn't help me in getting the angle I was looking for but it did point me in good direction.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @ae262 Yes, I know it doesn't tell you the angle you are looking for, sorry. I believe you would need the velocity vector to get that angle, not sure though. The sad news is, you cannot get an accurate estimate of the velocity with smart phones, simply because these senors are not accurate enough.